# How to add on numbers with tkinter on long press?

Tags: python, tkinter

In tkinter GUI,I have numbers it should goes on adding with previous number as long key is pressed. Stop when key is released. I have tried with `greenbutton.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', start_motor)` different events, I m unable to solve.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in way to do that, you will need to monitor for button press and release manually. This would be a great place to use a subclass of a Button. Like this:

```
import tkinter as tk

class LongPressButton(tk.Button):
    def __init__(self, master=None, command=None, repeat_time=250, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, **kwargs)
        self.command = command
        self.repeat_time = repeat_time
        self.command_trigger = ' '
        self.bind('<ButtonPress-1>', self.on_press)
        self.bind('<ButtonRelease-1>', self.on_release)

    def on_press(self, event=None):
        if self.command is not None:
            self.command()
        self.command_trigger = self.after(self.repeat_time, self.on_press)

    def on_release(self, event=None):
        self.after_cancel(self.command_trigger)

### TEST / DEMO:
def tick_func():
    print("tick")

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('200x200')
greenbutton = LongPressButton(root, text='click and hold me!!', bg='green', command=tick_func)
greenbutton.pack()
bluebutton = LongPressButton(root, text="I'm faster!!", bg='light blue', command=tick_func, repeat_time=80)
bluebutton.pack()
root.mainloop()
```